# Problems with refreshing terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, refresh, curses

I have problem with refreshing terminal. I'm using python with curses module. There is random name generator, which show generated name next to predefinied text at start program. User can modify name (add/remove chars).

Where is problem? At beginning at screen is showing only predefinied text. Generated name is entered but all characters are black and user cannot see it. Screen refreshed only when name is modified, ie user add new letter or delete last letter.

I would like to refresh screen just after generate name.

Algo: (part of GetStringName function)

```
    str = true_heroname #generated name
    self.screen.move(y, x + len(str))
    self.screen.refresh()                   #it should refresh screen after placing generated name
    self.screen.addstr(y, x, prompt, pattr)
    x += len(prompt)
    while True:
        self.screen.move(y, x + len(str))
        self.screen.refresh()
        ####AND BELOW CODE TO ADD/REMOVE LETTERS###
```

This function is used to generate name in main menu:

```
    self.name = Global.IO.GetStringName("What's your name? ", noblank=True, pattr=c_yellow, iattr=c_Yellow)
    #c_yellow and c_Yellow are predefinied colors
```

I hope description and code snipped are clear.

How can I made autorefresh screen after entered generated name?

Comment: There is not enough information (a short, complete program would help).

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't make your problem entirely clear to me, but maybe it helps if I point out a general way of drawing to the screen.
I assume that your self.screen is the actual curses `stdscr`.

```
while True:
    userinput = self.screen.getch() # User enters character

    # Move to start of terminal
    # This may not be necessary depending on your application
    curses.move(self.screen, 0, 0) 

    # Do your drawing here, depending on what char the user entered
    # ...
    self.screen.addstr("Hello world!")

    curses.clrtobot(self.screen) # Clear remainder of the screen
    self.screen.refresh() # Refresh terminal, to show new drawings
```